# Partial differenciation. What am i doing wrong here?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

\begin{array}{l}
\text { a) If } u=f(r), 
 r=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\\
\text { show, } \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}=f^{\prime \prime}(r)+\frac{1}{r} f^{\prime}({r})\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \times \frac{x}{r}\\
\text { Also } \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(u)=\frac{x \partial}{r \partial \gamma}(u)\\
\text { So, } \frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{x} {r} × \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)=\frac{x}{r} × \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} × \frac{x}{r}\right)\\
=\frac{x}{r} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial r^{2}} \times \frac{x}{r}-\frac{x}{r} \times \frac{x}{r^{2}} \times \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial r}
\end{array}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}} &=\frac{x^{2}}{r^{2}} \times \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial r^{2}}-\frac{x^{2}}{r^{3}} \times \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \\
\text { Similurily } \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}} &=\frac{y^{2}}{r^{2}} \times \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial r^{2}}-\frac{y^{2}}{r^{3}} \times \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \\
\text { So } \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}} &=\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{r^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial r^{2}}-\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{r^{3}} \times \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \\
&=\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial r^{2}}-\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \\
&=f^{\prime \prime}(r)-\frac{1}{r} f^{\prime}(r)
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us proceed slowly by your method. Hope you trace where you made an error in your calculation..

${\partial \over \partial x} = {x \over r} \times {\partial \over \partial r}$

Similarly,

${\partial \over \partial y} = {y \over r} \times {\partial \over \partial r}$

Now, let us calculate

$ {\partial \over \partial x} \left( 
{\partial u \over \partial x} \right) = 
{x \over r} \times {\partial \over \partial r}\left(
{x \over r} \times {\partial u \over \partial r} \right)
$

You need to be careful in using the product rule in evaluating the partial differentiation on the right hand side because x also involves r and it cannot be taken out as a constant. I feel this is where you made a mistake.

Now, let us evaluate using the product rule.

$ {\partial \over \partial x} \left( 
{\partial u \over \partial x} \right) =
{x \over r} \left[ {1 \over r} {\partial u \over \partial r} {\partial x \over \partial r} - {x \over r^2} {\partial u \over \partial r} + {x \over r} {\partial^2 u \over \partial r^2} \right]$

Note that

$ {\partial r \over \partial x} = {x \over r} $.

This gives you: ${\partial x \over \partial r} = {r \over x}$.

Thus, we simplify to get
$ {\partial \over \partial x} \left( 
{\partial u \over \partial x} \right) = {1 \over r} {\partial u \over \partial r} - {x^2 \over r^3}{\partial u \over \partial r} + {x^2 \over r^2} {\partial^2 u \over \partial r^2}$.      **(1)**

In a similar way (interchanging the roles of $x$ and $y$), we get

$ {\partial \over \partial y} \left( 
{\partial u \over \partial y} \right) = {1 \over r} {\partial u \over \partial r} - {y^2 \over r^3}{\partial u \over \partial r} + {y^2 \over r^2} {\partial^2 u \over \partial r^2}$.     **(2)**

Adding (1) and (2), and using $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$, we get

$ {\partial^2 u \over \partial x^2} + {\partial^2 u \over \partial y^2} = {2 \over r} {\partial u \over \partial r} - {1 \over r} {\partial u \over \partial r} + {\partial^2 u \over \partial r^2}$

That is,
$ {\partial^2 u \over \partial x^2} + {\partial^2 u \over \partial y^2} = {1 \over r} {\partial u \over \partial r}  + {\partial^2 u \over \partial r^2}$.

This completes the proof. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac {xu'(r)}{r}\right) = \frac {u'(r)}{r} + xu'(r)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac 1r\right) + \frac xr\frac{\partial (u'(r))}{\partial x}
$$

Comment: Yes , I know I can do it by this method. But in my book I have seen them substituting values of del/del(x) . Is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the two relations
$$
dr = \frac{1}{r} \mathbf{x}^T d\mathbf{x}
$$
and from chain rule
$$
\mathbf{g}
= \frac{\partial u}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
= \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
= \frac{f'(r)}{r} \mathbf{x}
$$
Differentiating gives
$$
d\mathbf{g}
= \left[
\frac{f''(r)r-f'(r)}{r^3} \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T+\frac{f'(r)}{r} 
\right] d\mathbf{x}
$$
It follows
$$
\mathbf{H}_x 
= 
\frac{f''(r)r-f'(r)}{r^3} \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T+\frac{f'(r)}{r} \mathbf{I}_2
$$
Taking the trace of the RHS
$$
\frac{f''(r)r-f'(r)}{r}+2\frac{f'(r)}{r}=
f''(r)+\frac{f'(r)}{r}
$$
which is the desired result.
This shows that you have missed the second term.